# Is there any way to determine the exception type with using exception message

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am wondering,How can i know the type of exception in .net when i get the exception message from my log file.

For Example:
Message: "`Error opening the file`" (Also exist stacktrace and source info in the log file)

I want to catch this exception in my try catch block.

Comment: Can you catch all exceptions and then find the type of the specific one.

Comment: Why not include a whole exception in your log file/the whole text in this message? If you look at a default exception "popup" like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i37Sc.jpg) one the name of the exception would be in front of the text.

Comment: Determining which exception type by evaluating the message, whilst it may work with some exceptions, is arguably not the best way to go about it.  For all we know there are multiple _"buffer full"_ exceptions coming from different aspects of .NET

Comment: yes its possible,but i am just reading the log file. I cant catch this exception at the time of debugging. Because It's so rarely

Answer (score 1):

With only the exception message and the stack trace you can not know the exact type of the exception with 100% certainty. This is simply due to the fact that the exception can be thrown with a custom message and not the built in default one.

The stack trace contains no information about the type of the exception either so that doesn't help much.

The best solution is probably modifying the logger so that it registers the exception type. Simply logging `exception.ToString()` would be enough, the overriden method returns `{Type}: {message} {stack trace}`. Hard to understand why the logger isn't simply registering that info already.